# Smarty: configuration file not found

Tags: php, templates, smarty

Trying to use Smarty properly, I created a config file. The file structure is like this:

```
/Smarty/
/Smarty/cache
/Smarty/configs
/Smarty/configs/main.conf
/Smarty/plugins
/Smarty/sysplugins
/Smarty/templates_c
/templates/
/templates/main.tpl
index.php
```

In main.tpl I try to load the main.conf from /Smarty/configs/main.conf by:
`{config_load "main.conf"}` as explained here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.config.variables.tpl
This doesn't work ("Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to read config file 'main.conf'' in..."), however this does work:

```
{config_load "/var/www/vhosts/*domain*/subdomains/cms/httpdocs/Smarty/configs/main.conf"}
```

Why doesn't the first example work? I did set the config dir earlier by:

```
$smarty->setConfigDir(SMARTY_DIR.'configs/');
```

But the config dir isn't found. Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Print `$smarty->getConfigDir()` after you call `setConfigDir` to see what path is actually there.

Comment: @Eugene The path seems to be correct. It print_rs: "Array ( [0] => /var/www/vhosts/*domain*/subdomains/cms/httpdocs/Smarty/configs/ )"

Comment: Can you check the file for permissions? Maybe the file does not have read permission.

Comment: @KaranPunamiya Set configs and main.conf to 777 for the occasion, but didn't change the errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got same problem, i have smarty integrate in CodeIgniter. and this is what i did 
1) `$this->smarty->addConfigDir('YourPath');`
in your case may become `$smarty->addConfigDir('YourPath');`

then print `var_dump($this->smarty->getConfigDir());` in the browser.
in your case may become `var_dump($smarty->getConfigDir());`

2) after that you may change `$this->smarty->setConfigDir('YourPath');`
in your case may become `$smarty->setConfigDir('YourPath');`

it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

here is sample of the config i use and it's working fine with me

```
/////Smarty including
require_once('libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = 'template'; // template folder
$smarty->compile_dir = 'cache'; // Create a Folder Cache with 777 Permission
```

This Settings works fine with latest smarty edition Smarty 3.x.